# Python with bs4 finding element in <script>

Tags: python, html, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access a value in  in an html / xml with bs4 but really can't find it. This is an example of what i'm trying to get:

```
<script>
  item1 = "a"
  item2 = "b"
</script>
```

I tried with this code:

```
for item in html.find_all('script'):
  if 'item1' in item:
    print(item)
```

but it doesn't work (nothing gets printed)...
Could anyone give a help with this?
Thank u a lot in advance

Comment: Could you please be more specific as for what _doesn't work_ means?

Comment: And what is `spree` here?

Comment: uh sorry, i edited a part but not everything

Comment: nothing gets printed if i run it like this

Comment: `html.find_all('script')` is going to give you a list with the contents of all `<script>` tags in the document. I believe BS4 will give you this as a list of objects, not of strings - and in particular, none will be exactly equal to the string `'item1'`. I believe you can use the `.get_text` method to find the actual text content, and then search that for a particular substring if you want.

Comment: i get "AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'" if I run it like that

Comment: Have you tried to print the `item` variable in the for loop?

Comment: yes, it prints all the scripts in the html

Answer (score 3):

Add `.text` and it prints the content of each `script`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scripts = '''
<script>
  item1 = "a"
  item2 = "b"
</script>
'''

html = BeautifulSoup(scripts)

for item in html.find_all('script'):
  if 'item1' in item.text:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: now i'm getting this error:
"AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: are you sure? try the whole script I posted

Comment: yep, i'm sure. i get the html from a request's response, prolly this is the problem

Comment: insert the requests code into the question, otherwise no one can help you. If you don't want to do this, please mark this answer as solution as it does what you want.